# Kotlin 2d array asignment

Tags: list, kotlin, assign

let's say I have a list defined in Kotlin:

```
val mylist = mutableListOf<List<Int>>(listOf(2,3,5), listOf(2,5,6))
```

Now, I want to assign a certain value to one of these sublists. For example, now that I have a list of

```
((2,3,5)(2,5,6))
```

I would like my list to be

```
((2,3,5)(2,100,6))
```

I'm used to doing this in Python by something like `myList[1][1] = 100`. How do I achieve the same result in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin has two sets of collection interfaces, the regular `List`, `Set`, etc. which are read-only, and the same ones with the `Mutable` prefix, which can be modified.

[`listOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of.html) will give you a [`List`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html) instance, while [`mutableListOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-list-of.html) gives you a [`MutableList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/index.html) instance. If you use the latter for creating your nested lists, you can use the exact syntax you've asked about:

```
val mylist: MutableList<MutableList<Int>> = mutableListOf(mutableListOf(2,3,5), mutableListOf(2,5,6))

mylist[1][1] = 100

println(mylist) // [[2, 3, 5], [2, 100, 6]]
```

(I've added the explicit type for `myList` for clarity's sake, it can be omitted from the left side of the assignment.)